# Starting X only gives a black screen, even if started with options

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, amd-catalyst

I just installed Arch from a live cd, set up network, installed wifi drivers, catalyst for my gpu (mobility hd 5470), xorg with all stuff it needs and then I started to try to use

```
startx gnome-session
```

and

```
xinit gnome-session
```

as well as starting it with/without xterm, but nothing ever appears, just a black screen, ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you get only a black screen, odds are that X is running.
Have you checked your /var/log/Xorg.0.log for errors?

I'd start my debugging by ruling out Gnome all together..
Install TVM and xterm (and xclock, alternativly comment that row out)

```
# pacman -S xorg-twm xterm xorg-xclock
```

Then copy the contents from the default xinitrc to yor local .xinitrc

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc > ~/.xinitrc
```

If twm starts with some terminals (and xclock) the problem is in your gnome session.
At least, if it works, you can now install a web browser and debug from within twm..

Also, please post your /var/log/Xorg.0.log if it does not work..
There might be a Catalyst problem, try using the open source driver if this fails (after checking your Xorg.log)..

Good luck

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Well. First of all thank you got the link. Second, I feel this comment falls under the "But I can't write a good answer without more information!" Part of the link you sent me. But it's a matter of opinion, and this answer is the first step to solving the problem. But if you still feel this answer is more of a comment, then you are welcome to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just run `startx gnome-session`. Properly configure your `.xinitrc` to boot GNOME, then just run `startx`. (Better solution: boot into GDM -- [instructions can be found on the Arch Wiki.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM))

Comment: Still, it doesn't show up anything when trying to run it by xinit/startx, only a black screen, from what I've read about it I should have access to somekind of interface after booting into X, so that's not really -that- helpful

Comment: Pastebin your .xinitrc and post a link here and I'll tell you if there's anything wrong with it.

Also, "startx" doesn't take any arguments. Make sure of that.

Comment: It was empty, after few hours I noticed that I had to use xorg1.12 not 1.13 because it's not supported by fglrx, it took some time to backport it

Comment: your .xinitrc shouldn't be empty if you're trying to use it with gnome-session... it should contain "exec gnome-session" or something similar.

Comment: Yea, I noticed that later aswell, still now I have another problem with it freezing and forcing me to hard-restart with almost no opned programs

Answer (score 0):

**In most cases, X11 will not initialize the mouse cursor until the first client has connected.**

I have no idea why.

A usable, no-fuss way to start X successfully is to do something like

```
X & sleep 1; DISPLAY=:0 xterm &
```

Possibly substitute `xterm` for another program like `urxvt` or even something like `openbox`. On exceptionally old systems (<2005) the `sleep` delay might need to be extended.

The ***right*** way to launch X is to use `startx` or `xinit` as these programs will start the X server, wait until it's running and can receive connections, and then execute the contents of `.xinitrc` - but if you don't want to edit config files the above command will work okay.

<sub>Source: for almost a year I've been using CTRL+SHIFT+R to relocate the above command in my history, and starting X that way. (I'm crazy, I know)</sub>